# How did the preposition "by" evolve its sense of "length x [by] width"?

Tags: etymology, prepositions

The preposition "*by*" has a lot of special uses, but its etymology is not so easy as [Etymonline wants us to believe](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=by).

How did "by" develop as a preposition for areas, giving the length and breadth?

Comment: Roger, you're not a novice here. Put a little more effort into formatting your question (as a bonus side-effect, it'll make its reception warmer). Before I saw your username, I thought this question was another drive-by by an anonymous and under-informed user.

Comment: You multiply something _by_ something else, which is what this type of measurement really is: length [multiplied] by width. I don’t know how German does this, but the Danish equivalent of _by_ in this sense is _gange_, which is literally ‘times’ and is exactly the same as in multiplications: _fem gange tre_ can either mean ‘five times three’ or ‘five by three’.

Comment: To be honest I found my 10 by 5 metres much simpler and clearer than your structural notation with brackets the sense of which is dubious.

Comment: @rogermue I did vacillate over that specific change.  Concrete examples often are more illustrative than abstractions. Feel free to put your 10m x 5m notation back if you like it better.

Comment: I think the only good information on this is gained secondarily by looking at OED entries. Since they list them historically, find the ones right before the 'multiplication' meaning and you'll have to judge what the jump really means.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  "multiplied by" is good, but how does "by" get a meaning like with or through (divided by) when you consider Etymonline's etymology that is mainly nearness?

Comment: "With" has an obvious connection to "nearness", no? "Through" seems like a simple evolution of that idea: they're so close, they're interpenetrating! (This is starting to feel like a dreamy deja vu of one of LePressentiment's questions!)

Comment: @rogermue Consider that the Romance languages also use the same preposition for _multiplied by_ and for expressing the agent in passive constructions—I'd say the multiplicand was likely originally (perhaps still, linguistically if not mathematically) thought of as the agent; i.e., _five is multiplied by seven_ = _seven multiplies five_ (though the active is not used, of course).

Comment: From the verb phrase _multiply `A` by `B`_ and its shortening into nominal-size lumber names -- _two-by-four, two-by-six, four-by-four,_ etc.

Comment: @LePressentiment Did you see this [later comment of mine which mentions you by name](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254561/how-did-the-preposition-by-evolve-its-sense-of-length-x-by-width#comment556322_254561)? The "anonymous and under-informed user" was a reference to the original, unformatted, version of the question which appeared on its face to be an impenetrable wall of text.

Comment: @DanBron Yes; I did. Sorry for any confusion; I intended my comment as a joke! rogermue: I upvoted this question.

Comment: @Dan Bron I'm a bit astonished about  your remark about my headline "Preposition  by - 10 by 5 metres". I chose this way as it is the form in which I would look for it in a register. The post is about the preposition by  and only about one special use of the 20 or 30 uses "by" can have. With the new headline I would have difficulty to find it after half a year. But actually I don't care how the headline is formulated.

Comment: @rogermue My remark wasn't about your headline specifically but how your entire post was formatted. Go compare them side-by-side, and if you don't think my edits are a substantial improvement, roll them back.

Answer (score 1):

Here's The [MED](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=13975766&egdisplay=open&egs=14171844) entry of the use of 'by' with numbers. See 10a.

The use in multiplication (and, by extension, when stating the dimensions of two sides) would appear to derive from the idea of 'in groups of N'.

3 x 4 = 3 by 4 =  "3 groups of 4".

```
xxxx
xxxx
xxxx
```

Comment: What is MED? And is this etymology? Does it explain how a preposition  whose central meaning is nearness according to  Etymonline develops a use that has nothing to do with nearness.

Comment: @rogermue: The MED is the Middle English Dictionary (out of Univ of Michigan).  Do you really think the notion of "groups" has "nothing to do with nearness'?

Comment: I thought of some mathematical dictionary. I use the Middle English Dictionary but it wouldn't be the one where I would look for an answer of the problem at hand. Well, groups and nearness? To be honest, I would say not very convincing. Etymology is not the art to bent crooked things right, but to really understand what has happened. And Etymononline has covered up all problems that arise with the heterogenous uses of "by".

Comment: But after thinking about your groups I now come to think that you might be up to something. One might say three groups of four, one beside the other. But how to explain division, nine divided by three?

Comment: Here we come into another problem that I wanted to exclude. The preposition by ( nearness, according to Eol, Etymonline) has developed as a preposition of agent (passive agent etc). A semantic jump that Eol does not explain and which actually is a real problem.

Comment: In Old English, the preposition 'bi' when prefixed to an intransitive verb makes the verb transitive.

Comment: Yes, that are the wonders of the chameleon by/be-. To behead expresses separation.